# Qprocess with powershell command still running

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, qt

I have a big problem with QProcess ( I use Qt c++ ). I need to execute a command with admin permissions ( windows 7 ) - netsh - I have to add exception to my firewall.

```cpp
proc->start("powershell",QStringList()<<"-Command"<<"Start-Process"<<"powershell.exe"<<"-Verb"<<"runas"<<"-ArgumentList"<<R"('here is netsh command')");
 proc->waitForStarted();
 qInfo()<<"before";
 proc->waitForFinished(-1);
 qInfo()<<"yeah!";
```

When I execute my program I see only "before". What can I do? I check my netsh command in powershell - it's good.

Comment: You should put the waitForFinished in a if loop to check if it's timeout, just to get an idea.

Comment: if (!proc.waitForFinished(-1))  
             qWarning() << "timeout";  
    else  
        qWarning() << "Yeah!" << endl;